# How do I respond to a tap on a UNUserNotification?

Tags: ios, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I'm using the new `UNUserNotification` framework in iOS 10. I can see how to add action buttons, but how do I respond when the user taps the notification itself? In my case, it will be an image with some text.

The default behavior is that the application opens.

1. Can I have custom code that detects if my application is being opened because of a `UNUserNotification` tap, and ideally with identifier information about the notification tapped?
2. Will these work if my app is running in the background or closed? `UNUserNotification` documentation suggests setting the delegate of `UNUserNotificationCenter`, but I think this only works if the app is running.

Comment: Doesn't `launchingOptions` contain this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `AppDelegate` to be `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` if you haven't already and add the following to the `didReceive` method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = ["identifier":response.notification.request.identifier]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "userNotificationCenterDidReceiveResponse"), object: self, userInfo: userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}
```

You can then register for that "userNotificationCenterDidReceiveResponse" notification and do whatever you like with the identifier. This works no matter what state your app is in, including not running.

If this isn't clear enough I can upload a sample project.

Comment: Huh! I thought this only worked if the app was running in the background. You're right, that's all I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNUserNotificationCenter Delegates`.

Use this when app is in foreground:

`- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler`

get the values to use from `notification`

And this when app is in the background:

`- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler`

get the values to use from `response`.

Hope this will help.