# Swift: doesn't call didReceiveRemoteNotification()

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

Here's my sample app

[image: At the left you can see the app delegate, on the right my view controller]

I've had some trouble with this in another app and I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong; It works like this:

1. I push a button that schedules the notification
2. I quit the app and close it
3. I wait for the notification to arrive
4. I restart the app through Xcode

The thing is: even though the didReceiveRemoteNotification()-function should be called, I still get false value when starting the app which shows me, that for any reason this method does not get called. Why? Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didReceiveRemoteNotification not called , iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10)

Comment: Are you scheduling a local notification??

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Post the text.

Comment: ah fdp come on I thought it would be a bit more clear when seeing both sides in comparison

Answer (score 2):

Method `didReceiveRemoteNotification()` is not supposed to be called for local notifications... It's only for remote notifications (Push Notifications).

Use `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` delegate method

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

See details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44142742/1825618

**Get delivered notifications** (Only the ones Currently being displayed in notification center)

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications {
    (notifications) in
    // your code
}
```

Comment: already tried that... my problem now is rather that the function is not working if I access the app through tapping on the app icon. It works only if I access the app through the notification itself. Do you know if I can generally detect wether or not a notification has arrived?

Comment: thats expected behaviour if you launch the app from the app icon, delegate method  won't be called. May be this will help you, by the time you open the app using app icon and your app notification is still being displayed in Notification Center, you can use this function to get all the delivered notifications `getDeliveredNotificationRequests:completionHandler:`

Comment: Thanks! And where can I call that function?