# How can I receive remote message from fcm in swift 4 when the app is not running?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, ios11, xcode9

I have already registered my app in Firebase console for my iOS application in Xcode 9, the problem I have is that I can receive the message just when the app is in background or suspend mode , and also can receive it in foreground.

1: I am using

```
Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/my-topic")
```

to subscribe to my topic.

and I send it with postman :

```
{
    "to":"/topics/my-topic",
    "content_available": true,
   "data":
   {
        "message": "some message.."
   }
}
```

2: I receive the message in the app delegate

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
```

.

How can I receive the message from the topic and do a local push notification when the **app is not running** ?

Comment: When app is not running `userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` method will be call just use this.

Comment: should i enable the content-available with the fcm Post ?

Comment: I tried to increment the badge number in this method but it doesn't work :( .. how can i register to userNotificationCenter  ?

Comment: I guess no need, I used `content_available = true` for silent push not for this case.

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44142742/1140335) when app is not active.

Comment: You need to register it in `appDidFinishLaunching:` method and tutorials are available on google.

Comment: i already registered but doesn't cannot receive the message in 

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response:...

Comment: Did you tap the notification in notification center ?

Comment: what you mean to tap the notification ?

Comment: App is minimized or kill... Notification came.... Did you click on that notification? How do you suppose how notification will show?

Comment: i tried to increment the badge number in the method , but id doesn't work ! that's mean the method is didn't receive the message !

Comment: You will have to send the badge number in push notification payload you can not change anything if app is not in running state. See [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) for more detail.

Comment: i don't want to send 
 "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message"
      }
in the payload , i want to get the remote message even the app is running or not ! and to decide to do push notification or not ! according to the data in the Fcm's payload

Comment: I know this is FCM but here too you can send badge. Without sending the badge its not possible.